# Laravel - some images not loading

Tags: laravel, image, backend

For some odd reason, some of the images on the website I'm working on are not loading on the entire website. I've tried removing the storage and relinking it, and clearing the cache and views, but it had no effect whatsoever.

I've triple checked that the images actually exist in their specified directories.

This is the path of an image that loaded:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/media/2/conversions/pc-icon.webp" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

This is a path of an image that doesn't load:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/media/1/conversions/what-includes-05-v03-icon.webp" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

(I've gotten the above paths from chrome's inspect element)

Comment: So in the developer tools, when you load the page, you see 404 for the missing images?  Check for red entries.

Comment: @Snapey I don't get a 404, I get the default image icon which looks fairly similar to [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F2%2F24%2FCircle-icons-image.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Far.m.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D9%2585%25D9%2584%25D9%2581%3ACircle-icons-image.svg&tbnid=-vx5y4f1GGQdpM&vet=12ahUKEwjjzYvz7I76AhUOqxoKHRjvBEgQMygBegUIARDjAQ..i&docid=6-4A7MKyHZA1IM&w=800&h=800&q=image%20icon&ved=2ahUKEwjjzYvz7I76AhUOqxoKHRjvBEgQMygBegUIARDjAQ)

Comment: Then you need to show the code that decides to show the default image icon instead of your image